# Authenticate a mobile device when its visiting a website without using any other applications

Tags: .net, angularjs, authentication, mobile, asp.net-web-api

We have a client requirement to authenticate a Mobile device whenever it accesses a specific URL, Since this is a rarely used functionality so this was decided to be done in **Website only**,
The website would be based on ASP.net/Web API for further calls and AngularJS in UI design

So kindly help me with the below questions with respect to the Authentication of a Mobile Device when accessing a Specific URL,

1. Do we have any way which can be used to authenticate a mobile device
   based on its unique identification?
2. But based on our analysis it is considered as a security risk to obtain data like IMEI , IMSI, MSISDN or Phone Number etc? Also efforts to extract those data on website access also failed, So do we have any other unique data which can be used as an authentication parameter?
3. If none of the above is feasible , Kindly suggest us any Ideas where a specific mobile device can be authenticated whenever it accesses a URL without any User Login or One Time Password or Flash Call authentication?
4. The URL being accessed will be provided to the user using a 3rd Party SMS service Provider, is there any data in SMS provider that can be used for authentication

Thanks,
Bala

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way in which a mobile device (not an app running on a mobile device) can be identified uniquely just by browsing to some URL.

However, since you mention you create the URL and send it to your mobile client, you can add a one time access allowed encrypted authentication parameter.

URL Example:
https://www.yourdomain.com/YourWebAPI/Authentication?p=jkshdksj!(sa

Then in your web api code (PSEUDU):

```
var decryptedParameter = Decrypt(p)

var validationResult = Validate(decryptedParameter)

if(validationResult == Success)
{
   RedirectToSite();
}
```

You can do whatever business logic you want in Validate()

Answer (score 0):

1. Nothing can be truly unique about a physical device. But the information it carries can be. The proper way of doing client based (as opposed to user based) authentication is to use a client certificate.
2. Unlike PKI certificates the types of information you enumerated can be made up easily given there is no integrity check on them. Even in a controlled networked server environment IP and MAC addresses are only used for connectivity restriction but not for authentication. I don't think you can collect them via the browser anyway.
3. If you just want to simplify the sign-in experience for your users on mobile device you may want to take a look at [this](https://readysignon.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use PKI and digital certificates. Your web server can trust a specific subordinate certificate authority and root certificate authority. The client mobile device can have a certificate issued by the subordinate certificate authority. On some phones, this certificate's private key can be located in the phone's TPM. Apple's iPhone has a secure enclave - it might be possible to store a certificate's private key there.